# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Terminal in java.library.path

Tags: java, terminal, java.library.path

I was trying to run the CHARVA Tutorial thru Eclipse after setting up the JAR,
but I receive

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Terminal in java.library.path

in the console. Any clue on how to fix this up?

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Linux?  Basically, CHARVA uses the NCURSES library and thus you'll need the appropriate DLL or .so file in your library path.

Comment: I am running Snow Leopard so terminal comes with the OS. I followed the instruction on http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/charva/Download.html but when I type in sh test.sh, nothing happened. not sure what is wrong....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Dave said, Charva requires a native library called Terminal to run. As far as I remember, it is included in the binary distribution for Charva.

Eclipse-specific instructions: In your project properties, select Java Build Path, then Libraries. Locate the jar and set the Native library location to the path where the Terminal library is.

Comment: Thanks, you are right that libTerminal is included, but adding to the native library path didn't work for me.